# MS Powerpoint 2007

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am using MS Powerpoint 2007 for a Training Presentation with links to other files and objects on slides that can be moved around for demonstration purposes. How can I deploy the Training Presentation and prevent saving unauthorized changes??

Answer (score 0):

You can mark it as final or export it to pdf, but both would disable not only saving but changing as well.

I guess that the easier solution is to have it on some server (everyone gets his own copy to change, unchanged version stays on server) or in a shared folder (Users are allowed only to read the file (not to change it) by file system privileges, when they open it they can edit but cannot save the file to original location (thay can save it to different location though)).